# Port project from STM8 to STM32

Tags: arm, microcontroller, stm32

I am trying to port a set of files, written for a STM8 microcontroller, to a STM32 microcontroller. But I am not sure how to start.

The firmware on the STM8:
http://www.st.com/web/en/catalog/tools/PF258104

And I want to rewrite it so that it can run on this board: http://www.st.com/web/en/catalog/tools/FM116/SC959/SS1532/PF253215?s_searchtype=keyword

There are some sample programs available for the STM32, and I think it's possible. I just need some advise on how to take this on, since there are some controller specific files in the STM8 firmware which need to be rewritten so they can run on the STM32.

Thank you.

Matthijs

Comment: STM8 != ARM Microcontroller

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit too broad. You should instead dive into trying to convert the code yourself, and ask question about specific details that you do not know how to port over to the new arcitecture, or understand what their original purpose is.